# CollectionView ItemsSource binding visual update (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding

I tried to make some MVVM pattern into my app, and i ran into a problem with hte visual representation of data. The data if the binded observablecollecrion is updated, but the visual is not.
some code:
ViewModel:

```
public class HlavnaViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public HlavnaViewModel()
    {
    }
    

    private Doklady _selectedDok;
    public Doklady vm_selectedDok
    {
        get => _selectedDok;
        set
        {
            _selectedDok = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(vm_selectedDok));
            update_polozky();
        }
    }

    public async void update_polozky()
    {
        Polozky dok = new Polozky() { id_doklad = _selectedDok.id };
        ObservableCollection<Polozky> pol = new ObservableCollection<Polozky>(await App.Database.GetPolozkyAsync(dok));
        vm_polozky = pol;
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Polozky> _polozky;
    public ObservableCollection<Polozky> vm_polozky
    {
        get => _polozky;
        set
        {
            _polozky =value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(vm_polozky));
        }
    }
}
```

in the XAML:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="polozky" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding vm_polozky}">...
```

BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

finally in View:

```
public Hlavna()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        hvm = new HlavnaViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = hvm;
        
    }
```

if i select a row in CollectionView where the vm_selectedDok binding is set, it selects that item, fires the update_polozky(), the vm_polozky gets populated with the right data, but the visual just dont shows the items from vm_polozky.

Ive read couple of similar questions, but i cant figure out where i made a mistake.

**EDIT:**
so the problem was somewhere else, i had the grid.rowdefinitions set just wrong, therefore the grid was outside of the visible area.

@ToolmakerSteve made good suggestions on calling async/await, please read his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two alternative ways to fix this.

---

One way is Gerald's answer. This is fine for small collections, but *might* be slower if there are many items being added.

---

The second way is to do what you've done - replace the collection. But there is a fix needed in your code.

The way you've called `update_polozky` won't work reliably. You don't start the `async/await` sequence inside an `await`.

Replace:

```
update_polozky();
```

With:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
    await update_polozky();
});
```

---

OPTIONAL: Might also make this change. (Though it shouldn't be necessary.) This gives a good place to put a breakpoint, to see whether "result" gets the expected contents.

Replace:

```
ObservableCollection<Polozky> pol = new ObservableCollection<Polozky>(await App.Database.GetPolozkyAsync(dok));
```

With:

```
var result = await App.Database.GetPolozkyAsync(dok);
ObservableCollection<Polozky> pol = new ObservableCollection<Polozky>(result);
```

---

IMPORTANT NOTES FOR OTHER CODERS:

The second approach ("replace the collection") relies on `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(vm_polozky));` in the `setter` of the `ObservableCollection`.

You have that, so not an issue for you. I mention this for anyone else who might adapt this code.

For example, I've seen people attempt to set the private value directly, e.g.:

```
// Don't do this to replace the collection. XAML won't know you changed it!
_myPrivateField = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>(result);
```

I've also seen people try to have an ObservableCollection without a setter:

```
// This is okay UNLESS you replace the collection - in which case you need `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyCollection))` somewhere:
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection { get; set; }
```

Comment: Pushing things only on the UI thread isn't also very great in terms of performance and also doesn't work in this case. Replacing the `ObservableCollection` with a new instance will break data-binding to the UI unless you set it again afterwards.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve great suggestions, thanks.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - sorry, but my experience says otherwise. I’ve used this code multiple times. 1) performance on UI thread - async/await should handle this well, assuming all called code is properly written for await. That’s the raison d’etre for async/await!! If code might cause delay, I invoke on separate thread then invoke back to main thread when list is ready. 2) Replacing the entire list at once is MORE performant in XF than adding items one at a time. 3) Data-binding - As I mentioned, that requires OnPropertyChanged. OP already has this in their code. See vm_polozky setter.

Comment: Then I'm probably not understanding you correctly :) glad it got resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Basically it comes down to, don't do this: `ObservableCollection<Polozky> pol = new ObservableCollection<Polozky>(await App.Database.GetPolozkyAsync(dok));`

Whenever you create a new `ObservableCollection` it will lose the databinding to the UI. Clear your `ObservableCollection` with `.Clear()` and add new items to it with a `for` loop. For example:

```cs
public async void update_polozky()
{
    Polozky dok = new Polozky() { id_doklad = _selectedDok.id };
    var results = await App.Database.GetPolozkyAsync(dok);

    vm_polozky.Clear();

    foreach(var item in results)
        vm_polozky.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: CAVEAT: This is fine for small collections, but *might* be slow if there are many items - each `Add` triggers a UI update in Xamarin Forms. (Ideally the foreach loop will finish before XF tries to display, but I've had problems in the past.) When many items, the approach OP is attempting to do is what I recommend. However there is a bug in the code shown in question. (I've added an answer that attempts to fix that bug.)

Comment: the code above works correctly, but it shows databinding is still kept on creating new ObservableCollection, so it is fine to use it that way too.

Comment: @Taliga - right; the OnPropertyChanged in vm_polovsky setter tells Xamarin to update any XAML bound to vm_polovsky.